# Fundemental group of $A \cup B$ with a non-connected intersection.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> Let $X = A \cup B$, where $A,B$ are open simply connected subspaces such that $A \cap B$ consists of $n \geq 1$ path-connected components.
> Prove that $\pi_1(X) \simeq \mathcal{F}_{n-1}$, the free group with $n-1$ generators.

Intuitively i can see $X$ is "similar" to the bouquet of $n-1$ copies of $S^1$, which from Van-Kampen's theorem has the fundamental group $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$, but i couldn't formally show any connection between the spaces (such as a deformation retraction that retracts $X$ to $\bigvee_{i=1}^{n-1} S^1$)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you reading?

Comment: @Moishe The question is from a course on algebraic topology passed in my university, which from my understanding is based mostly on Hatcher's book

Comment: You should make it clear in the OP, since there are radically different approaches to this problem, say, using groupoids or group actions on trees.

Comment: @Anne yes, Thank you!

Comment: Well, the only answer in a duplicate is not really a proof but a lot of handwaving (as its author honestly admits). There is another dupe, but the answer there is by Ronnie Brown who, of course, uses groupoids.